# Data item propagation only when "executed" by task's blocks

Tags: .net, architecture, tpl-dataflow

I'm just starting using TPL Dataflow, so I might be using some wrong terminology.
I'm designing a process in which it a Data item should be operated by multiple blocks (each one should check a condition of some kind, and verify or decline this piece of data).

Only when a specific Data item was verified by **all** blocks (I still don't know which type exactly this block should be), it can be proceed with additional work by a linked block.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow is a pipeline of steps that process messages. There is no concept of verifying or voting, but it can be emulated:

1. Each rule block should emit a `Vote<T>` result that contains both the original message, a vote (eg, True/False, or Yes/No/Maybe).
2. All rule blocks should be linked to a custom `Ballot<T>` block that aggregates votes by message and emits the result. `Aggregates` may simply mean that you have a dictionary keyed by MessageID that contains the votes. When enough votes are collected to reach a decision, you emit a Result containing the message and the outcome.
3. Outgoing links from the Ballot block should have a filter that redirects eg sucessful messages to the next normal step, while failed messages are sent to logging. You can speficy the filter by using the [LinkTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194832(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts a Predicate, ie a lambda that returns true/false based on the message value

Separating Ballot from the actual redirection means that it's a lot easier to program the Ballot, while you have the flexibility to redirect messages as needed. You could, for example, allow partial fails to proceed, or send them to a post-processing step etc. Or perhaps, use a quorum rule where X out of Y votes mean success.

Comment: Thanks, @panagiotis. I can't see how I'll be calculating "...enough votes" (from your answer), because the `Ballot<T>` instance is "un-aware" of the number of `Votes<T>` instances. The result should be affected by all the linked rules.